# App Install CTA Not Showing in Instant Article

Tags: facebook-instant-articles

I created an App Install CTA in Instant Article but it's not showing. My instant article source is RSS feed. Do I have to add any code in RSS??

Please help. Thanks in advance

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Only those who doesn't have you app installed will see the CTA. I had the app installed & that's why I didn't see it.